# What is the difference between [asymptotics], [big-o-notation], and [landau-notation]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [asymptotics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotics) tag currently has two tags remapped to it: [big-o](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o) and [asymptotic-complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotic-complexity). I can imagine the reason [landau-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landau-notation) is not amongst those is to distinguish between questions about asymptotics (in general) and the notation *itself* (and possibly its definition too); this seems to be what the tag description also hints at:

> Questions about asymptotic notations such as Big-O, Omega, etc.

However, is there a good reason [landau-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landau-notation) is not synonymous with [big-o-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o-notation) (as in, e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_symbols))? Does [big-o-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o-notation) merit its own tag? Its description currently reads:

> Big O Notation is an informal name of the "O(x)" notation used to
>   describe asymptotic behaviour of functions. It is a special case of
>   [landau-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landau-notation).

So, is [big-o-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o-notation) a special case of [landau-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landau-notation), which, in turn, is a special case of [asymptotics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotics)? How are they related to the [notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) tag?

Answer (score 6):

In the context of CS, "Big-Oh Notation" is probably a synonym of "Landau Notation", even though there is more than O to Landau notation. I'd propose to get rid of the extra tag.

Both are subsets of asymptotics, which covers different types of bounds and limit processes. I think it makes sense to keep the different tags.

Comment: I agree. Big-O and Landau are synonyms, at the level we're dealing with. But I think it's worthwhile distinguishing between, e.g., "Please help me give an asymptotic analysis of this algorithm" (where the answer will probably be expressed using Landau notation but the question is about much more than that) and "How  can I tell if f(n)=O(g(n))?" (which is solely about relationships between [mathematical] functions).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've been less vigilant about it recently, but for a long time I rigorously retagged the former with [tag:algorithm-analysis+runtime-analysis], leaving [tag:landau-notation] and/or [tag:asymptotics] only on such questions that were _about_ those things. I still think this distinction is meaningful and helpful, but unfortunately many teachers seem to disagree.